# Java tree generation breadth first?

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

First off I'm really sorry if this question will seem stupid to most of you,which it might.
However I'm somewhat new to programming and java in general , and what I'm trying to do here is use a generic tree for some project I'm working on.

The rule is any parent node can have as many children as possible.

Also I want to generate the tree by breadth , which is proving problematic for me.
Is there any good Tree library for this or should I implement my own ADT ?

I'll need it to solve some basic AI problems , like the Farmer,Fox,Grain,Chicken problem.

```
 public class Tree<T> {
   private Node<T> root;

   public Tree(T rootData) {
    root = new Node<T>();
    root.data = rootData;
    root.children = new ArrayList<Node<T>>();
   }

   public static class Node<T> {
    private T data;
    private Node<T> parent;
    private List<Node<T>> children;
  }
 }
```

This is what I have up until now. All I need is to figure out how to add nodes in a breadth first manner.

Mind you , I only need to be able to add data. I don't care about deletion and root switching for now.

Comment: Is this homework? If it is, tag it as homework. And it would be great if you provide some code

Comment: @rpax *Homework* tag is extinct long back.

Comment: It's not homework , it's me trying to learn on my own. I'll provide some code in a sec.

Comment: Edited.Added the tree code I have for now.

Comment: What exactly does "breadth first" mean here? Since you have unlimited children, you could just append all nodes directly below the root node...? But if that's the idea a flat list would probably be a better idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing a similar program a few years ago, for Breadth First Search using multiple children. What you need to do is modify the Node class to something like this:

```
class BFSNode {
    int val;
    BFSNode parent;
    LinkedList<BFSNode> allChildren = new LinkedList<BFSNode>();
}
```

The Linked List is useful for holding all the childrens together. Here is the complete code, it was written to find the Breadth First Search Algorithm (Note it is probably a very inefficient program, but it gets the job done)

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

class BFSNode {
    int val;
    BFSNode parent;
    LinkedList<BFSNode> allChildren = new LinkedList<BFSNode>();
}

public class BFSTree {
    BFSNode root = null;

    public void add(int insertVal, int parentVal) {

        BFSNode newNode = new BFSNode();
        newNode.val = insertVal;
        BFSNode parentNode = null;

        if (root == null) {
            root = newNode;
            System.out.println("Added insertVal :" + insertVal + " at parent :"
                    + root.val);
        } else if (root.val == parentVal) {
            root.allChildren.add(newNode);
            System.out.println("Added insertVal :" + insertVal + " at parent :"
                    + root.val);
        } else {
            parentNode = BFS(parentVal);
            if (parentNode == null) {
                System.out.println("Parent does not exist");
            } else {
                parentNode.allChildren.add(newNode);
                System.out.println("Added insertVal :" + insertVal
                        + " at parent :" + parentNode.val);
            }

        }

    }

    public BFSNode BFS(int parentVal) {
        BFSNode markBfsNode = root;

        LinkedList<BFSNode> childrenQueue = new LinkedList<BFSNode>();

        while (true) {

            for (int i = 0; i < markBfsNode.allChildren.size(); i++) {
                if (markBfsNode.allChildren.get(i).val == parentVal) {
                    return markBfsNode.allChildren.get(i);
                } else {
                    childrenQueue.add(markBfsNode.allChildren.get(i));
                }
            }

            if (childrenQueue.getFirst() == null) {
                System.out.println("Element not found");
                return null;
            } else {
                markBfsNode = childrenQueue.getFirst();
                childrenQueue.poll();
            }

        }
    }

    public void printBFS() {
        BFSNode markBfsNode = root;

        LinkedList<BFSNode> childrenQueue = new LinkedList<BFSNode>();
        System.out.print(root.val + "   ");

        while (true) {

            for (int i = 0; i < markBfsNode.allChildren.size(); i++) {
                childrenQueue.add(markBfsNode.allChildren.get(i));
            }

            try {
                if (childrenQueue.getFirst() == (null)) {
                    return;
                } else {
                    System.out.print(childrenQueue.getFirst().val + "   ");
                    markBfsNode = childrenQueue.getFirst();
                    childrenQueue.poll();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return;
            }

        }

    }


}

class BFSImplementation {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        BFSTree obj = new BFSTree();
        obj.add(5, 0);

        obj.add(7, 5);
        obj.add(9, 5);
        obj.add(11, 5);
        obj.add(15, 5);

        obj.add(17, 9);
        obj.add(19, 9);
        obj.add(21, 9);

        obj.add(23, 19);
        obj.add(27, 19);

        obj.add(29, 7);
        obj.add(31, 7);

        obj.add(33, 11);
        obj.add(35, 11);

        obj.add(37, 21);
        obj.add(39, 21);

        obj.add(111, 29);
        obj.add(111, 29);
        obj.add(111, 29);

        System.out.println();
        obj.printBFS();
    }
}
```

Comment: Managed to solve it in the mean time , but thank you regardless :).